# Form being processed but not redirecting

Tags: php, html, forms

Since this morning I am trying to redirect to a new page when a form is submitted. I realized that the form is being processed because the info is being saved in the database. However, when saved, I want to show a page with the new created info. The page is not showing.

Here is the form code

```
<form action='index.php?view=newOffice' name='form_cliente' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' onsubmit='return validarFormularioCliente()'>

<div class='box1'>
    <div class='title1'>
        <div class='required_field1_title'>* campos obrigatórios</div>
        Criar cliente
    </div>
    <div class='content1'>
        <?php 
        if($erro_sql){
            $style_display = "";
        }else{
            $style_display = "style='display: none;'";  
        }
        ?> 
        <div id='error_box' class='error_box' <?php echo $style_display; ?> >
            <div class='error_message' id='erro_nome' style='display: none;'>Introduza um <b>Nome de Cliente</b></div>
            <?php 
            if($erro_sql){
                ?><div class='error_message'>Ocorreu um erro. Por favor tente novamente.</div>
            <?php }
            ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Colocar abaixo a tabela com dados de input -->
        <table class='table1' width='100%' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1' border='0'>
            <tr>
                <td class='table_title1 required_field1'>* Nome do Cliente</td>
                <td class='table_text1'> 
                    <input class='text_field1' type='text' id='nome_cliente' name='nome_cliente'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<table width='100%' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type='submit' value='guardar'>
        &nbsp;
        <?php echo "<input type='button' onclick='window.location = \"".$CONF['HOME']."/superadmin/\"' value='cancelar'>"; ?> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the php which processes the code and redirect to the page I want to show

```
    //verifica por routing qual a vista que foi chamada. Se for sobre um novo cliente, grava-o
    if(strcmp($view, "newOffice")== 0 && !empty($_POST['nome_cliente'])){

        $nome_cliente = addslashes($_POST['nome_cliente']);
        $codigo_escritorio = $crm_escritorio->guardar_escritorio($nome_cliente);

        if(!empty($codigo_escritorio)){
            $link = "index.php?view=escritorio&id=".$codigo_escritorio;
            //$view="escritorio";
            header("location: ".urldecode($link));  
        }else{
            $erro_sql = true;
        }
    }
```

and the view switch case

```
case "escritorio":
    include(box_visualizar_cliente.php");
    break;
```

Finally, the code of the page I want to show.

```
        //instanciar as classes necessárias para obter a informação
    /*if(!isset($crm_escritorio))$crm_escritorio = new crm_escritorio;

    if(!empty($codigo_escritorio)){

        $resultGetEscritorio = $crm_escritorio->getEscritorioById($codigo_escritorio);

        if(!empty($resultGetEscritorio) && sizeof($resultGetEscritorio) == 1 ){
            echo "<div class='box1'>";
            echo "<div class='title1'>";
            echo "<div class='option1'>";
            echo "<a href='index.php?view=edit&amp;id=".$codigo_escritorio."'>editar</a>";
            echo " | <a href='index.php?view=delete&amp;id=".$codigo_escritorio."' onclick='return confirm(\"Tem a certeza que pretende apagar?\")'>apagar</a>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "detalhes do cliente";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='content1'>";
            echo "<table class='table1' width='100%' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1' border='0'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='table_title1'>Nome do Cliente</td>";
            echo "<td class='table_text1'>";
            echo $resultGetEscritorio[0]['esc_nome'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }*/
?>
<div class='box1'>
<div class='title1'>detalhes do utilizador</div>
<div class='content1'>
<div class='empty1'>nao foi encontrado nenhum contacto</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Anyone can tell me what is missing? I will tank you forever!!!

Comment: Are you sending any (HTML) output before the `header("location: ".urldecode($link));`?

Comment: Is the user re-directed anywhere, at-all? By default, the `action` tag in a `form` element should specify where you want the user to be re-directed to.

Comment: Yes, I have a template page which contains menu's and things like that. I am making an intership and the company gave me an website to add functionalites. I am trying to clone the forms but I am missing something!

Comment: It is redirected to the index page which processes and saves the info form...I know it its a bad practise but the website it is already build like that. After saving, is the index who makes de header(). Unfortnatly, the page is not showing up as expected.

Comment: If HTML output is sent before the header, the header won't be send, as the headers were already sent with the first output. You could use for instance http://php.net/ob_start to buffer the first output so that you _can_ actually add more headers at this point.

Comment: The thing is some code is made like that and it works. I really am missing something, but thank you, I will see that :)